# How can I use while loop with "try" and "except"?

Tags: python, try-except

I am new with "try" and "except" keyword in Python, today I learned it and tried to write a program that allows users to enter an integer, if they did not enter an integer, they will enter again. My idea is I will use the while loop with "try" and "except", but it seems like the while loop is not working in the situation.

```
error = False
while error == False: 
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        error = True
    except:
        error = False
```

Is there anything that I missed? Thank you guys

Comment: "it didn't work" doesn't give us much to go on. Was there an error message? Can you give us a more specific description of what happened?

Comment: It should be other way around. `error = True` should be in `except:` block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @Gram: Due to the way the loop test is written, that change would result in the loop ending once an invalid input is made, instead of ending upon a valid input.

Answer (score 2):

More elegant way of doing this would be

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```